# SQL request to find similar values if they respect some conditions

Tags: sql

I have a specific problem and i didn't find any ressources to help me. Maybe i looked badly or maybe it's not possible to do what i want. I just changed the name of my columns but the spirit stays the same.

| ID | ID_House | ID_Postman | ID_Vehicule |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | H1 | P1 | V1 |
| 2 | H1 | P1 | V3 |
| 3 | H1 | P2 | V1 |
| 4 | H1 | P2 | V2 |
| 5 | H2 | P1 | V1 |
| 6 | H3 | P1 | V1 |
| 7 | H4 | P3 | V3 |

Is it possible to find the ID_postman in common with a list of ID_House but it most be strict ?
If example, if i want the ID_postman in common with [H1,H2,H3], i must have :

| ID_Postman |
| --- |
| P1 |

But if I want the ID_postman in common with [H1,H2,H4], i must not have results.

where ID_house in ('H1','H2','H4') => result : none where ID_house in ('H1','H2','H3') => result : P1

Comment: please add the DBMS you are using. SQL != SQL ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems tricker than it first appears but try the following as a possible solution, it should work in most compliant RDBMS platforms standard analytic functions.

```
with x as (
    select id_house, id_postman, 
      Count(*) over(partition by id_postman) pq
    from t
    where id_house in ('h1','h2','h3')
    group by id_house,id_postman
)
select id_postman
from x
where pq=(select Count(distinct id_house) from x)
group by id_postman
```

See [working Fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3722691e57136af72d3fc12ba7246558)

Comment: Thank you ! I have the good answer with this. It's a pity that there is not an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of problem.
To solve it I found a unique way to represent the value targeted as concatenation of string ordered.

With windows function (or just GROUP BYs) you could link each postman with his ids_house

Something like

| ID | ID_House | ID_Postman | ID_Vehicule | IDs_House |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | H1 | P1 | V1 | H1_H2_H3 |
| 2 | H1 | P1 | V3 | H1_H2_H3 |
| 3 | H1 | P2 | V1 | H1 |
| 4 | H1 | P2 | V2 | H1 |
| 5 | H2 | P1 | V1 | H1_H2_H3 |
| 6 | H3 | P1 | V1 | H1_H2_H3 |
| 7 | H4 | P3 | V3 | H4 |

The tricks is to be sure to have no ambiguity in your id_house gathering, use an order by.

More elegant ways should exist to fix it but it worked for me.

Comment: Actually it's interesting and you could provide with related SQL code. Then finalize your query in checking the list oh values we are looking for, at the end you will have one single query doing the job ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Probably you're looking for a request like this:

```
SELECT ID_Postman FROM my_table
WHERE ID_House IN ('H1', 'H2', 'H4);
```

Comment: This will return P1 And P2

Comment: It's not that i want.
where ID_house in ('H1','H2','H4') => result : none
where ID_house in ('H1','H2','H3') => result : P1